# What circumstance is this operator overload dealing with in C#?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

Take this class and operator overload:

```
public class Test
{
    public static Test operator +(Test test)
    {
        return test;
    }
}
```

Ignoring the implementation simply returning "test" for now, in what circumstance would this operator overload be called? It is valid and compiles, but I cannot work out what it's for!

It only takes one parameter, so what it is adding?

Comment: Seems pretty useless, but there *is* a unary `+` operator. It's kind of like the opposite of negation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691365(v=vs.71).aspx. It would be called if someone did `+someTestObject`, obviously.

Comment: maybe you would like to increase a value of a property when `+` is applied to an instance of `Test` ? I don't know why you would though, but there are some crazy developers out there who might...

Comment: @itsme86 yep that's what it is exactly (see the answer below), it's been driving me crazy but not sure why I didn't think of this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so what it is adding?

I think it does not add anything but determines a polarity in a sense.
I guess it would be comparable to a sign saying negative and positive like in

```
int i = +5;
```

This compiles just fine:

```
Test t1 = new Test();    
Test t2 = +t1;
```

but this doesn't:

```
Test t4 = -t1;
```

It compiles after the addition of

```
public static Test operator -(Test test) { return test; }
```

Here is what [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewkkxkwb.aspx) has to say to the unary + operator

> The result of the unary plus operator (+) is the value of its operand
>
> The unary negation operator (–) produces the negative of its operand